# Discord.py bot not responding to mute command

Tags: python, discord, bots

Im trying to make a mute command in discord.py and everything seems to be correct. Whenever i use the command then my bot doesn't respond with the message i've gave it, and it doesn't give the muted role. Here's the code:

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
    await user.mute(reason=reason)
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    mute = discord.Embed(title=f"User {user.name}#{user.discriminator} has been muted. <a:m_verifyblack:850825891780100096>", color=0xF4D03F, description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
    await user.send(embed=mute)
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**:no_entry_sign: You cant do that!**")```
````

Comment: You are missing `commands.command`, or whatever you use, at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the `@client.command` (if you did `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix")` at the beginning of the file under imports) at the beginning of the command. To fix this you would do

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your_prefix")

@client.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    mute = discord.Embed(title=f"User {user.name}#{user.discriminator} has been muted. <a:m_verifyblack:850825891780100096>", color=0xF4D03F, description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
    await user.mute(reason=reason)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=mute)
    await user.send(embed=mute)

@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**:no_entry_sign: You cant do that!**")
```

Also you seem to be using an outdated version of discord.py . Try switching to [**Pycord**](https://pycord.dev/), which is a maintained fork of the now-deprecated discord.py. I'm not quite sure what `user.mute` does, but hopefully I answered your question.